# How to handle javascript inside html template

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some JavaScript inside one of my template files that set ups some JavaScript objects related to the template.

```
        <hr class="statcard-hr mb-0">
      </div>
      <canvas id="chart-ph" width="378" height="94" class="sparkline"
        style="width: 200px; height: 50px;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</table>
</div>

<script>
  //populate initial chart data
  getSensorData('recent');

  //create chart
  createChart('chart-temp', 10, 30);
  createChart('chart-hum', 20, 60);
  createChart('chart-ec', 500, 2800);
  createChart('chart-ph', 4, 8);
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that the template file is loaded before the main .js files (that are loaded in the bottom of the base template). So createChart and getSensorData are not defined. I am curious how you normally would go about structuring this.

To me it makes sense to set up the JavaScript objects in the template, but I guess usually people do it in another way?

Comment: You'd usually have the javascript in a seperate file and only inject the script into the DOM when you actually need it. So if you write your template in such a way that it can render without the script, you can later add the script again at any time to add that functionality to the rendered template. If your page Needs javascript to run to actually be visible, there's a flaw in the architecture you use.

Comment: Your are using `javascript` inside your html file. Simple move it to the `.js` file or load your file first.

Answer (score 0):

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." So you can use this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //Your script
});
```

or you can use $(function())

Just place your code above your template. Remove it from bottom and put it on top.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your function calls inside document ready like below

```
<script>
  $(function() {
      //populate initial chart data
      getSensorData('recent');

      //create chart
      createChart('chart-temp', 10, 30);
      createChart('chart-hum', 20, 60);
      createChart('chart-ec', 500, 2800);
      createChart('chart-ph', 4, 8);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! I tried this, but jQuery is not loaded either. Should I load it in the head section instead to make sure it is always loaded?

Right now, I only load .css files there.

Comment: You can add the jQuery before this script block or in header.